# Move pawn/character to random point within specific area on the map

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'd like to add some sort of "properties" to different areas of the level so they can affect NPC behavior.

Level layout:
[level layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIXsn.png)

What NPC behavior I want to achieve:

1. NPC can freely walk around Area #1
2. NPC isn't allowed to go to Area #4 in general but it may decide to go there in some exceptional cases
3. If NPC wants to interact with the player he has to go to Area #2 and check if player is in Area #3. If player is not there, NPC have to wait until player enters Area #3

I know that I can affect the path NPC chooses by using navigation modifier volumes and changing navigation cost in some areas.

But, based on goals above, I also need at least the following

1. I need to get random point within specific area (for goals #1 and #3)
2. I need to check if some actor is in specific area (for goal #3)

And I guess I don't really need "navigation cost" feature, since if I could get random point in **specific** area, I would be able to control where NPC goes anyway

The questions are:

- What actor should I use to mark some areas as "NPC can go here if they want to walk around", "NPC can go here if they want to interact with player", etc?
- If volume is the best option, what volume should I use? My concerns about Navigation Modifier volume is that I don't really need to modify navigation process by blocking it completely or adjusting its cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the **NavMeshBoundsVolume** to define the area that my AI character is allowed to be in.

Then I used **blackboards** and set points the AI could walk around too, adding variables enabling or disabling a point. In your case you could have a variable that is true when the player is in area #3.
[image: Example of blackboard with keys]

I've included a picture of my Behavior Tree, so that you can get an idea of the how a flow might look. This is for an "enemy," but you could simply have the AI follow the character to a specific area instead of playing the attack animation and applying damage.
[image: Behavior Tree]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNJEvAGiw7w&list=PL4G2bSPE_8ukuajpXPlAE47Yez7EAyKMu) is a really good series on AI in Unreal Engine. It's UE4 but if you are familiar with the engine you shouldn't have a problem applying it to UE5.

Comment: I used `Vector` and `TargetPoint` to set route points but both options seem a bit hardcoded. In the AI series you shared they use `GetRandomPointInNavigableRadius` but it provides you with point in circular area. 

I need random point from rectangular area. I've created actor with box collision and placed its instances around the level. Now I can get random point via `RandomPointInBoundingBox` and track when NPC / Player enters any area via `OnComponentBeingOverlap`. 

I wonder if it's proper solution or just a workaround

Comment: That solution seems fine to me